# generate combination of List string in java

Tags: java, string, for-loop, arraylist, combinations

I have a List called listTeams which comprises of Strings. I need to generate all unique combinations of these strings and store them in another ArrayList called lines. I've tried the following but the results are not desirable:

```
for(int i=0; i<listTeams.size();i++){
    for(int j=1;j<listTeams.size();j++){
       if (listTeams.get(j).equals(listTeams.get(i)))
                    continue;

           for(int k=2;k<listTeams.size();k++){

                if (listTeams.get(k).equals(listTeams.get(i)) || listTeams.get(k).equals(listTeams.get(j)))
                    continue;
                String str = listTeams.get(i)+listTeams.get(j)+listTeams.get(k);
                lines.put(str,new ArrayList<String>());                 
                }
             }              
           }
```

Here's the original list : {"A","B","C","D"}
What I am getting is

```
a_b_c
a_b_d
a_c_d
a_d_c
b_c_d
b_d_c
c_b_d
d_b_c
```

What I desire is:

```
a_b_c
a_b_d
a_c_d
b_c_d
```

Comment: C_B_D? Do you want that too?

Comment: Maybe you could try `for(int j=i+1` and `for(int k=j+1`

Comment: @KristjanKica No, I've edited my qs. Thanks!

Comment: @Berger Thanks a lot!! It worked like a charm!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for(int i=0; i<listTeams.size();i++){
    for(int j=i+1;j<listTeams.size();j++){
           for(int k=j+1;k<listTeams.size();k++){
                String str = listTeams.get(i)+listTeams.get(j)+listTeams.get(k);
                lines.put(str,new ArrayList<String>());                 
                }
             }              
           }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to modify your for loops like this:

```
for (int j = i;
```

and

```
for (int k = j;
```

So that only unique combinations appear

Answer (score 0):

As #Berger said, the following code is working as you expect.

```
for (int i = 0; i < listTeams.size(); i++) {
            for (int j = i+1; j < listTeams.size(); j++) {
                if (listTeams.get(j).equals(listTeams.get(i)))
                    continue;

                for (int k = j+1; k < listTeams.size(); k++) {

                    if (listTeams.get(k).equals(listTeams.get(i)) || listTeams.get(k).equals(listTeams.get(j)))
                        continue;
                    String str = listTeams.get(i) + listTeams.get(j) + listTeams.get(k);
                    lines.add(str);
                }
            }
        }
```